# Compare two list values having integer numbers

Tags: java

I have the following two lists

```
List<Integer> list1 = {23, 45, 62, 12, 34};

List<Integer> list2 = {45, 48, 67, 14, 37};
```

I need to check that the values in list2 are greater than corresponding values in list1, i.e.

45 > 23 , 48 > 45 , etc

How can I write a logic for this?

Here is the code I tried but it is not working

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list1.add(41);
    list1.add(31);
    list1.add(60);
    list1.add(10);
    list1.add(30);

    List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list2.add(46);
    list2.add(34);
    list2.add(66);
    list2.add(17);
    list2.add(39);

    for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < list2.size(); j++) {
            if (list2.get(j) < list1.get(i)) {
                System.out.println("tune time not optimized");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does it mean for one list to be greater than another? When all elements are greater? When most elements are equal? What if only some elemenets are greater, are they equal then? It is unclear to me what you want to compare and what the result would be.

Comment: It looks like you only have to verify that the i'th element of list2 > the i'th element of list1. If this true?

Comment: If the 2 lists will have the same size, you can do this in one loop

Comment: if List<Integer> list1 = {23, 45, 62, 12, 34};

List<Integer> list2 = {45, 48, 67, 14, 37}; \n 45 > 23 , 48 > 45 , 67 > 62, 14 > 12 , 37 > 34

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the lists have been validated to have the same size, you can use:

```
boolean tuneTimeOptimized = true;
for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
    if(list2.get(i) < list1.get(i)) {
        tuneTimeOptimized = false;
        break;
    }
}

if(!tuneTimeOptimized) {
    System.out.println("tune time not optimized");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this logic will work

```
for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("list2: " + list2.get(i));
            System.out.println("list1: " + list1.get(i));
            if (list2.get(i) < list1.get(i)) {
                System.out.println("tune time not optimized");

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check only the i'th element

```
for (int i = 0; i < list2.size() > list1.size() ? list1.size() : list2.size(); i++) {
    if (list2.get(i) < list1.get(i)) {
        System.out.println("tune time not optimized");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether the second List greater than the first one, then this solution can help you:

```
static boolean isSecondListGreater(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b) {
    Integer nbGreaterNumber = 0;
    for (Integer elementA: a ) {
            if (b.get(a.indexOf(elementA)) > elementA) {
                nbGreaterNumber++;
            }

        }
    return nbGreaterNumber == a.size();
}
```

PS: both Lists have to have the same size

Answer (score 0):

Here is how one might approach it using `streams` but the simple iterative solution is probably best.

```
        List<Integer> list1 = List.of(23, 45, 62, 12, 34);
        List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>(List.of(45, 48, 67, 14, 37));

        // Use Math.min to prevent a index related exception
        boolean allGreater = IntStream.range(0, Math.min(list1.size(), list2.size()))
                .allMatch(i -> list2.get(i) > list1.get(i));
        System.out.println(allGreater);

        // now check the other case
        list2.set(2, 45);

        allGreater = IntStream.range(0, Math.min(list1.size(), list2.size()))
                .allMatch(i -> list2.get(i) > list1.get(i));
        System.out.println(allGreater);
```

Note that this solution will return true if all the elements of the shorter list will satisfy the requirements against the longer list.